# What is the meaning of "Guess they figured jobs is easier to come by than hair"?

Tags: idioms

This appears in "[Seven Men from Now](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0049743/)" from 1956:

> Soldier boys come riding through
> three days ago.
> Claimed the Injuns was fixin'
> to kick up their heels.
> Then we seen war fire
> in them hills to the south.
> So they all just up and took off
> like a scalded dog.
> Guess they figured jobs
> is easier to come by than hair.
> I'm the only one stayed behind.

Comment: Do note that the dialect is illiterate/rural, so don't try to over-analyze it.  But Andrew's answer mentioning "scalping" is likely correct.

Answer (score 4):

It would appear to mean that deserting from the army for a regular job is an easier thing to do than grow hair back after being scalped by "Injuns".